# Making a table in LaTeX with merged columns

Tags: tables

How do I make a `table` in LaTeX as shown below?

[image: Table expected]

Comment: Sorry, but this looks horrible. I bet there is a better way of representing the information, are you open for suggestions?

Comment: Do you try to do anything regarding this table? Pleas show your effort! Retyping your table is not quit fun job ...

Comment: The table is easy, but it does not look nice

Comment: Any other ideas for a better format? @Zarko I am working on it and hope to provide some test soon

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX, though :o)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, just now I'm to lazy for retyping the table :-( .

Comment: @Zarko: I had a similar one already -- stock answer, basically ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A suggestion: Merging the A,B,C,D identifiers with M/S respectively, deleting all vertical lines and removing almost any horizontal lines (the 'bad' layout' is below)

'Omitting' cells can be done with `\multicolumn{1}{c}{}`, i.e. empty multicolumn statements. Partial horizontal lines are done with `\cline{startingcolumn-endcolumn}` etc.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\begin{document}

{\bfseries
\begin{tabular}{*{9}{c}}
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{8}{c}{Treatment 1} \tabularnewline
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &  MA & SA &  MB & SB &  MC & SC &  MD & SD\tabularnewline
\midrule[2pt]
F1 &   1 & 2 &  3 & 4 &  5 & 6 &  7 & 8\tabularnewline

F2 &   1 & 2 &  3 & 4 &  5 & 6 &  7 & 8\tabularnewline

F3 &   1 & 2 &  3 & 4 &  5 & 6 &  7 & 8\tabularnewline

F4 &   1 & 2 &  3 & 4 &  5 & 6 &  7 & 8\tabularnewline

\tabularnewline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{8}{c}{Treatment 2} \tabularnewline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} &  MA & SA &  MB & SB &  MC & SC &  MD & SD\tabularnewline
\midrule[2pt]
F1 &   1 & 2 &  3 & 4 &  5 & 6 &  7 & 8\tabularnewline

F2 &   1 & 2 &  3 & 4 &  5 & 6 &  7 & 8\tabularnewline

F3 &   1 & 2 &  3 & 4 &  5 & 6 &  7 & 8\tabularnewline

F4 &   1 & 2 &  3 & 4 &  5 & 6 &  7 & 8\tabularnewline

\end{tabular}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Just for comparision: The bad table layout** -- Judge yourself...

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}


\begin{document}

{\bfseries
\begin{tabular}{|*{9}{c|}}
  \cline{2-9}
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{8}{c|}{Treatment 1} \tabularnewline
  \cline{2-9}
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &  \multicolumn{2}{c|}{A}&  \multicolumn{2}{c|}{B} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{C} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{D} \tabularnewline
  \cline{2-9}
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &  M & S &  M & S &  M & S &  M & S\tabularnewline
\hline
F1 &   1 & 2 &  3 & 4 &  5 & 6 &  7 & 8\tabularnewline
\hline
F2 &   1 & 2 &  3 & 4 &  5 & 6 &  7 & 8\tabularnewline
\hline
F3 &   1 & 2 &  3 & 4 &  5 & 6 &  7 & 8\tabularnewline
\hline
F4 &   1 & 2 &  3 & 4 &  5 & 6 &  7 & 8\tabularnewline
\hline
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{8}{c|}{Treatment 2} \tabularnewline
  \cline{2-9}
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &  \multicolumn{2}{c|}{A}&  \multicolumn{2}{c|}{B} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{C} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{D} \tabularnewline
  \cline{2-9}
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &  M & S &  M & S &  M & S &  M & S\tabularnewline
\hline
F1 &   1 & 2 &  3 & 4 &  5 & 6 &  7 & 8\tabularnewline
\hline
F2 &   1 & 2 &  3 & 4 &  5 & 6 &  7 & 8\tabularnewline
\hline
F3 &   1 & 2 &  3 & 4 &  5 & 6 &  7 & 8\tabularnewline
\hline
F4 &   1 & 2 &  3 & 4 &  5 & 6 &  7 & 8\tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can I somehow change the font styles/size?

Comment: @SimonB: Remove `\bfseries`, for example and replace it with `\large` etc. This depends on your choice, of course. For choosing a completely different font family use a font package

Comment: Thanks. And if I want to add a title to the table. How can I proceed?

Comment: @SimonB: You mean the caption?

Comment: Yeah. I have tried `\caption{}` right after the `\begin{tabular}` but it does not work.

Comment: @SimonB: `\captionof{table}{your caption}` --you need the `caption` package for this

Answer (score 2):

Here is a variant:

```
    F1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 \\
    F2 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9\\
    F3 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
    F4 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11\\
```

[image]

Comment: The left justification of `Treatment` disrupts the look, in my point of view, but that's perhaps only my opinion

Comment: @Christian Hupfer: I did it on purpose, due to the F_i column, which itself disrupts symmetry in the layout, not to mention the use of boldface for ‘Treatment’. To my taste, it looks better than centred, especially if there is a centred caption. You can try modify it and tell me if you have some time, I'd be curious to have your opinion comparing both possibilities.

Comment: No, it's just my opinion. I would not use it this way -- it's only a 'tiny' feature of your nice solution (+1)